# AspectJ: variable transfer from one matching advice to another

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have two advices matching the same pointcut. They are supposed to be performed one after another. For example:

```
pointcut som(TargetClass t, CallingClass c): target(t) && this(c) && call(public * TargetClass .*(..) );

before(TargetClass t, CallingClass c): som(t, c) 
{
    System.out.println("Entering: " + thisJoinPoint);
    String identifier = <...>; //Generating unique identifier for a method call
    getMonitor().addRecord(identifier, new Date()); //Sending new record to a custom monitor object
}

after(TargetClass t, CallingClass c): som(t, c) returning
{
    getMonitor().finishRecord(identifier, new Date());
}
```

This is how I see the logic in general. The problem is how to make a variable created in the "before" advice available in the "after" advice. I do not know ApsectJ well enough to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the corrected version of Stefan's answer (sorry, but I cannot post it as a comment because of the formatted code):

```java
public aspect MyAspect {
    pointcut som(TargetClass t, CallingClass c) :
        target(t) && this(c) && call(public * TargetClass .*(..) );

    Object around(TargetClass t, CallingClass c) : som(t, c) {
        System.out.printf("%s%n  this   = %s%n  target = %s%n", thisJoinPoint, c, t);
        String identifier = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        getMonitor().addRecord(identifier, new Date());
        Object result = proceed(t, c); 
        getMonitor().finishRecord(identifier, new Date());
        return result;
    }
}
```

- `around()` advices need a return type matching the pointcut or, for lack of better knowledge, `Object`.
- The parameter list for `proceed()` must match the advice's one.
- Unless the return typ is `void`, you need to return the result of `proceed()` (modified or unchanged or even a compeletely different object of the same type replacing the original). You can even skip `proceed()` if you always want to return another object and stop the original method from being executed altogether.
- If you want to do something else after proceeding, but before returning the result, you need to buffer the result.

Comment: Thx, that was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: Then I will be happy about you accepting and upvoting the answer. Thanks.